# VB-Macros to split two strings and insert them as a new row and trim function

Tags: excel, vba

I am kind of new to Excel Macros. I have a sample data for which I am trying to write a macro which should perform multiple operations. In the attached excel sheet you could see multiple track# across a single Network#, I want to a put individual track# across there corresponding network#'s and when doing so the space should  be trimmed between the N and the number following.

raw data in excel:

```
X33652  N 4230047169                            2013/11/28()
X34704  N4230644769, N4230645169                2014/06/04/m/RB CLRD
X40110  N4230854369, N 4230846569               2014/06/04/B/No Mega
X40605  N 4320617605,N 4320617705,N 4320617805  14/06/12/MayS/CANCELLED/attached email
```

Ex: Desired output for row 3 is

```
X40110  N4230854369             2014/06/04/B/No Mega
X40110  N4230846569             2014/06/04/B/No Mega
```

I am kind of stuck with no help. Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. its VBA

Comment: Please post where you are stuck at in your code

Comment: I tried to trim the values but I couldn't proceed as it showed syntax error. As I told before I am just a newbie to macros :(

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Range("A1:A").Value = Replace$(trim("A:A"), " ", "")

End Sub

Comment: Is there any experts out there who can help me out?

Comment: I am still not clear what you intend to do. Can you accomplish the same using simple excel formulas first? if so please show that

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Guys it looks crisp and more understandable. I appreciate it

Comment: @hnk: I doubt if this could be done in simple excel formula! Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions:

Prerequisites: Sheet1 contains original data (track# in column A, data to split in column B and comment/date in column C), Sheet2 will contain processed data.

Hope that helps.

The code (click Alt+F11, click Insert/Module, paste the code in the inserted module):

```
Sub test()
Dim a As String, g As String, k As String, l As String
Dim b As Long, c As Long, d As Integer, e As Integer, f As Long, h As Integer, i As Integer, j As Long
b = 1
j = 1

While IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A" & b)) = False 'does not check if exceeding excel row limit
 b = b + 1
Wend

For c = 1 To b 'Or "2 to b" if data has headers (if first row contains column names)
    a = Sheet1.Range("B" & c) 'If column B contains the data to split
    k = Sheet1.Range("A" & c) 'network #
    l = Sheet1.Range("C" & c) 'date or comment
    d = Len(a)
    h = 0
    For e = 1 To d
        If Mid(a, e, 1) = "," Or e = d Then
            If h = 0 Then
                If e = d Then
                    i = e
                Else
                    i = e - 1
                End If
                g = Mid(a, 1, i)
                While IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("B" & j)) = False 'does not check if exceeding excel row limit
                    j = j + 1
                Wend
                Sheet2.Range("A" & j) = k
                Sheet2.Range("B" & j) = g
                Sheet2.Range("C" & j) = l
            Else
                If e = d Then
                    g = Mid(a, i + 2, e - i - 1)
                Else
                    g = Mid(a, i + 2, e - i - 2)
                End If
                While IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("B" & j)) = False 'does not check if exceeding excel row limit
                    j = j + 1
                Wend
                Sheet2.Range("A" & j) = k
                Sheet2.Range("B" & j) = g
                Sheet2.Range("C" & j) = l

                i = e - 1

            End If
            h = 1
        End If
    Next e
Next c

Dim m As Long, o As Integer
m = 1 'Or 2 if top row contains headings
Dim n As String
While IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("B" & m)) = False
    Sheet2.Range("B" & m) = Trim(Sheet2.Range("B" & m)) 'trim
    n = Sheet2.Range("B" & m)
    For o = 1 To Len(n)
        If Mid(n, o, 1) = " " Then n = Left(n, 1) & Right(n, Len(n) - 2) 'remove single space
    Next o
    Sheet2.Range("B" & m) = n
    m = m + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Try this code (Update according to the comments):

```
Sub test()

Dim srow As Integer

srow = MsgBox("Does the first row contain data headers (column names)?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "First row selection")
If srow = 6 Then
    srow = srow - 4
Else
    srow = srow - 6
End If

Dim a As String, g As String, k(16383) As String, l(16383) As String
Dim b As Long, c As Long, d As Integer, e As Integer, f As Long, h As Integer, i As Integer, j As Long
b = srow
j = srow

While IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A" & b)) = False And b < 1048576
    b = b + 1
Wend

b = b - 1

If srow > b Then MsgBox "No entries to analyze!", vbInformation, "Attention!": Exit Sub

Dim spli As String

INPU:
spli = InputBox("Please, enter the Letter of the column, which contains the data to split", "Define split column")

If Len(spli) > 3 Or Len(spli) < 1 Then MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU

Dim letc As Integer

For letc = 65 To 122
    If letc <> 91 And letc <> 92 And letc <> 93 And letc <> 94 And letc <> 95 And letc <> 96 Then
        If Left(spli, 1) = Chr(letc) Then Exit For
        If letc = 122 And Left(spli, 1) <> Chr(letc) Then MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU
    End If
Next letc

If Len(spli) > 1 Then
    For letc = 65 To 122
        If letc <> 91 And letc <> 92 And letc <> 93 And letc <> 94 And letc <> 95 And letc <> 96 Then
            If Mid(spli, 2, 1) = Chr(letc) Then Exit For
            If letc = 122 And Mid(spli, 2, 1) <> Chr(letc) Then MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU
        End If
    Next letc
End If

If Len(spli) = 3 Then
    For letc = 65 To 122
        If letc <> 91 And letc <> 92 And letc <> 93 And letc <> 94 And letc <> 95 And letc <> 96 Then
            If Right(spli, 1) = Chr(letc) Then Exit For
            If letc = 122 And Right(spli, 1) <> Chr(letc) Then MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU
        End If
    Next letc

    If Left(spli, 1) = "Y" Or Left(spli, 1) = "Z" Or Left(spli, 1) = "y" Or Left(spli, 1) = "z" Then
        MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU
    End If
    If Left(spli, 1) = "X" Or Left(spli, 1) = "x" Then
        If Asc(Mid(spli, 2, 1)) < 65 Or (Asc(Mid(spli, 2, 1)) > 70 And Asc(Mid(spli, 2, 1)) < 97) Or Asc(Mid(spli, 2, 1)) > 102 Then
            MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU
        End If
        If Mid(spli, 2, 1) = "F" Or Mid(spli, 2, 1) = "f" Then
            If Asc(Right(spli, 1)) < 65 Or (Asc(Right(spli, 1)) > 68 And Asc(Right(spli, 1)) < 97) Or Asc(Right(spli, 1)) > 100 Then
                MsgBox "Please, enter a valid Letter of a column", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!": GoTo INPU
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

Dim coll As Long, colr As Long, coun As Long

RECL:
coll = InputBox("How many columns to the left of the split data column would you like to copy?", "Left Columns")

If Sheet1.Range(spli & srow).Column - coll < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Wrong number of columns indicated", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    GoTo RECL
End If

RECR:
colr = InputBox("How many columns to the right of the split data column would you like to copy?", "Right Columns")

If Sheet1.Range(spli & srow).Column + colr > 16384 Then
    MsgBox "Wrong number of columns indicated", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    GoTo RECR
End If

For c = srow To b
    a = Sheet1.Range(spli & c)
    For coun = 0 To coll - 1
        k(coun) = Sheet1.Cells(c, Sheet1.Range(spli & c).Column - 1 - coun)
    Next coun
    For coun = 0 To colr - 1
        l(coun) = Sheet1.Cells(c, Sheet1.Range(spli & c).Column + 1 + coun)
    Next coun

    d = Len(a)
    h = 0
    For e = 1 To d
        If Mid(a, e, 1) = "," Or Mid(a, e, 1) = "/" Or e = d Then
            If h = 0 Then
                If e = d Then
                    i = e
                Else
                    i = e - 1
                End If
                g = Mid(a, 1, i)
                While IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range(spli & j)) = False And j < 1048576
                    j = j + 1
                Wend
                For coun = 0 To coll - 1
                     Sheet2.Cells(j, Sheet1.Range(spli & c).Column - 1 - coun) = k(coun)
                Next coun
                Sheet2.Range(spli & j) = g
                For coun = 0 To colr - 1
                     Sheet2.Cells(j, Sheet1.Range(spli & c).Column + 1 + coun) = l(coun)
                Next coun
            Else
                If e = d Then
                    g = Mid(a, i + 2, e - i - 1)
                Else
                    g = Mid(a, i + 2, e - i - 2)
                End If
                While IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range(spli & j)) = False And j < 1048576
                    j = j + 1
                Wend
                For coun = 0 To coll - 1
                     Sheet2.Cells(j, Sheet1.Range(spli & c).Column - 1 - coun) = k(coun)
                Next coun
                Sheet2.Range(spli & j) = g
                For coun = 0 To colr - 1
                     Sheet2.Cells(j, Sheet1.Range(spli & c).Column + 1 + coun) = l(coun)
                Next coun

                i = e - 1

            End If
            h = 1
        End If
    Next e
Next c

Dim m As Long, o As Integer
m = srow
Dim n As String
While IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range(spli & m)) = False
    Sheet2.Range(spli & m) = Trim(Sheet2.Range(spli & m)) 'trim
    n = Sheet2.Range(spli & m)
    For o = 1 To Len(n)
        If Mid(n, o, 1) = " " Then n = Left(n, 1) & Right(n, Len(n) - 2) 'remove single space
    Next o
    Sheet2.Range(spli & m) = n
    m = m + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)
But it process only three columns< I just gave an example with three columns but my actual data has many columns to it. Help please

Comment: many columns with data to split? Or Many columns to transfer with the processed data?

Comment: Many columns to transfer with the processed data

Comment: Then just add variables to the for loop. in the code k and l are the two strings that transfer along the processed data, if you need more to transfer add respective variables and references.

Comment: Hi  user3565396 : now I have a problem, my requirement changed. now the column which contain data to split is column 23 and I have total of 28 columns. your expertise will be much appreciated. Thank

Comment: I have a question few of my data are like this 1286253 / 2260158
1286253/ 2260158
So how do I add those conditions? since the above code just removes the space but not "/".
Help please

Comment: Hello Emily. Could you tell me does the first row of your data contain headings (names of columns)? For the second question: Do you want to keep numbers or add "N" to them?

Comment: user3565396 : Yes it has names of columns. my data is mix of string and numbers. So these data does not start with N its just a number by itself but separated by '/' as given in my previous comment. Thanks for the help

Comment: user3565396 : Should I call you Genius? that was so perfect user3565396 :):) Thank you very much :)

Comment: I am just wondering rather than inputting the character say for example column 23 we input as 'W' can this changed to feed just  as number. say 23 for 23rd column? it makes it easy rather than alphabet

Comment: Need your help please!

Comment: :))) it is not critical. Try yourself. Bye.

Comment: I tried but dont know to change much as im a newbie to VBA. Help this time please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to

```
Dim i as Long, Temp1 as Str, Temp2() as Str, TempArr() as Str

For i = 1 to 100 ' For e.g. you need 100 rows
   Temp1 = Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("A"&i))
   TempArr = Split(Temp1," ")
   Temp2 = Split(TempArr(1),",")

   If Ubound(Temp2) = 1 Then
      ' i.e. There are 2 values in the second cell, 
      ActiveSheet.Range("B"&i) = TempArr(0) & " " Temp2(1) & " " & TempArr(2)
   Else
      ' Do nothing
   End if

   ActiveSheet.Range("B"&i) = TempArr(0) & " " Temp2(0) & " " & TempArr(2)
Next i
```

This is extremely inefficient but will give an idea how it can be done.

Comment: Thank you.This is for Trimming the values right but I need to split the values into rows and then trim it. how do I do that

Comment: are you looking for two rows in one row as an output?

Comment: I am looking for 2 or 3 rows(based on the data) of output from single row of input

Comment: I am not clear what you are looking for. Please simplify your question replacing the long strings and any unnecessary information with only the bare essentials , like "Abc" in cell A1 needs to become "A" in cell B1 and "bc" in cell B2.

Comment: output I got with below code is : 
X1       A1        123         abc

         A2 

but my desired output is :
X1      A1         123         abc

X1      A2         123         abc


Just need a help duplicate the other values of column to the second row...any help please?

Comment: Option Explicit
Sub splitcells()
  
  Dim InxSplit As Long
  
  Dim SplitCell() As String
  
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    RowCrnt = 1
 Do While True

      If .Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      SplitCell = Split(.Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value, ",")

Comment: RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

    Loop

  End With

 End Sub

Sorry for the splitted code space constraint in comment box

Comment: and need to incorporate trim function in the same piece of code