# Normalize concatenated Excel data

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has data like this:

```
Task  |TaskRepeat  
Task1 |M,W,F  
Task2 |T,Th
```

I would like to transform it to this:

```
Task1  | M  
Task1  | W  
Task1  | F  
Task2  | T  
Task2  | Th
```

I am familiar with VBA, but use it a lot more in Access than Excel. Is there an Excel solution to this task (either a formula or VBA)?

Comment: A formula would be pretty complicated IMO, but you can certainly write a VBA function to extract the comma-separated values and dump the data onto a new sheet, depending on your needs. So the answer is yes, there's a solution (there's always a solution! ;) ...but at this stage it's a little too early to ask on this site, I suggest you come back if/when you're stuck with a specific programming issue while implementing your VBA code. Good luck!

Comment: I promise I searched for a reasonable amount of time before posting, but after posting I found this answer that helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114109/splitting-a-string-text-into-separate-rows-in-vba

Comment: Do you still need vba written or not as i have free time to write it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, it assumes your list is in Col A and B and will put the List in D and E and that the data starts on row 2

```
Sub Normalize()

    Dim lngFirstRow As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim cRow As Long
    Dim shSrc As Worksheet
    Dim lngNextDestRow As Long
    Dim varDay As Variant
    Dim arrDays() As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lngFirstRow = 2
    lngNextDestRow = 2


    Set shSrc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With shSrc

     .Range("D1") = .Range("A1")
     .Range("E1") = .Range("B1")

      lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

      For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow Step 1

           arrDays() = Split(.Range("B" & cRow), ",")

            For Each varDay In arrDays
                .Range("D" & lngNextDestRow) = .Range("A" & cRow)
                .Range("E" & lngNextDestRow) = varDay

                 lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 1
            Next varDay

        Next cRow
    End With

         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```