# Converting multiple columns of data into a single row for each column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset with multiple columns. For every cell in column A, there is a variable number of cells in the other columns. Looking for help making a macro that creates a single row for every combination of column A with the corresponding cells in other columns. Example input:

```
Posted on   Tags
3/8/15  Tag A
3/8/15  Tag B, Tag C
3/8/15  Tag C, Tag B, Tag D
3/9/15  Tag D
3/10/15 Tag D, Tag F
3/10/15 Tag B
3/10/15 Tag D, Tag E

Desired output:

Posted on   Tags
3/8/15  Tag A
3/8/15  Tag B
3/8/15  Tag C
3/8/15  Tag C
3/8/15  Tag B
3/8/15  Tag D
3/9/15  Tag D
3/10/15 Tag D
3/10/15 Tag F
3/10/15 Tag B
3/10/15 Tag D
3/10/15 Tag E
```

Comment: This is a coding support site - not a "free coders who are bored write my code for me" site. Write at least one line of code yourself and I would help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Normalize concatenated Excel data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186684/normalize-concatenated-excel-data)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if those comas were showing each column or are actually part of the value.

I assumed that each type was merely in its own column like this:

[image: Before Data Fix]

The macro assumes that you run it while the sheet that contains the types is active and that the "fixed data" will be placed on "Sheet2"

If this is not the case, change/add sheet references.

```
Sub FixMyData()
'x will iterate through each row on our ActiveSheet from 1 to the last row
'y will iterate through each column (Tag) if there are more than 2
'z will keep track of the row we are outputting to on Sheet2
Dim x, y, z

z = 1 'Start outputting on row 1

'This line just speeds up macros that modify sheets significantly
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Start at the first row on our active sheet and iterate through each one
For x = 1 To GetLastRow(ActiveSheet.Name, 1)
    'This is a new row so get the date and put it on sheet2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(z, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1)

    'Grab the first tag (if it exists) and put it there too
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(z, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2)

    'We're ready to output to the next row
    z = z + 1

    'If there is more than one tag on this row
    If GetLastCol(ActiveSheet.Name, x) > 2 Then

        'Let's read through each one and output it in the same way
        For y = 3 To GetLastCol(ActiveSheet.Name, x)
            'Stick the date on Sheet2
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(z, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1)

            'And stick the tag next to it
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(z, 2).Value = Cells(x, y)

            'We're ready to write to the next row again
            z = z + 1
        Next y
    End If
Next x

'Format column A on Sheet2 as dates (since we're not using copy)
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & GetLastRow("Sheet2", "A")).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Helper functions that make the code easier to read
'They return the last Row/Column (respectively) with data
'-------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetLastRow(sheet As String, col As Variant) As Integer
GetLastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Sheets(sheet).Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
End Function
Function GetLastCol(sheet As String, row As Variant) As Integer
GetLastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, Sheets(sheet).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: I realize comment instructions said not to write thanks, but feel compelled - thanks very much for this. I wasn't expecting a full write-up of code, just pointing in the right direction in terms of what logic to use to get it done. So, very grateful - will dig into your code and try to figure out how it actually works. Thanks again, Andrey.